# Where is my web traffic coming from?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, lighttpd

I run a webapp created in Rails, for years it worked just fine. Then for the last couple of days it would be down at 9:50am, 10:50am, etc

I get the feeling that I'm being hammered by another site and but I have no way of checking. How do I see where my web traffic is coming from? How do I see if a large portion of it is coming from a particular IP, or a particular person, etc?

I run Debian, Rails, Lighttpd, mysql

Comment: Have you looked at your traffic logs? Perhaps installed Google Analytics?

Comment: Look into the web server's log files, they should be able to tell you more.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to (as mentioned above), review the web server logs, likely in /var/log/lighttpd.